# Application design with API and database access

Tags: c#, database, rest, architecture

I am trying to make an application that will load sports data (teams, players, games, etc...) from API and save into the database (with an update once a day) for subsequent analysis (in C#, but I think the language is not that important). The application composes from two parts, one for GUI and second for working with database and API.

My question is: Is it a good idea to use the same classes eg. for teams or players in model for both API and database? I know that one class should have one responsibility, but separate classes seam to me like a little overhead and even bring complications. But maybe I am wrong because I donť have enough experience with architecture design.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the two classes are the same class that should serve both projects, you can create instead a shared DLL holds you class by adding additional project to your solution, write the class you need and reference it to both project.

This will make your DLL to be apart of the two applications without writing your code twice.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I will try to put the model classes into shared DLL.